# Extend WP Query & return output in $post

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to create an event site. Users at the moment can search for events within a specified radius of their chosen search location (using Google Geocode).

I have a custom DB Query, which works fine, except I want the distance of the event to display on the front end of the site also, so users know how far away each event is from them.

Here's the custom query function I have at the moment:

```
function location_posts_where( $where ) {  

            // if user has input a location
            if( isset($_POST['where']) != '' ) :

                // check the geo locaton of user
                $geoURL = "http://freegeoip.net/json/". $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] .'';
                $geo = json_decode(file_get_contents($geoURL), true);

                // Geocode input value + users country code
                $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode($_POST['where'])."+".$geo[country_code]."&sensor=false";
                $location = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

                // store lat and long of searched location
                $Slat = $location[results][0][geometry][location][lat];
                $Slng =  $location[results][0][geometry][location][lng];

            // if use hasn't unput a location
            else :

                // get location of user
                $url = "http://freegeoip.net/json/". $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] .'';
                $geo = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);

                // store lat and long of user location
                $Slat = $geo[latitude];
                $Slng = $geo[longitude];

            endif;


            // Specify the co-ordinates that will form  
            // the centre of our search  
            $lat = $Slat;  
            $lng = $Slng; 

            $radius = $_POST['distance']; // (in miles)  

            // Append our radius calculation to the WHERE  
            $where .= " AND wp_posts.ID IN (SELECT post_id FROM lat_lng_post WHERE 
                 ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(" . $lat . ") ) 
                                * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
                                * cos( radians( lng ) 
                                - radians(" . $lng . ") ) 
                                + sin( radians(" . $lat . ") ) 
                                * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) <= " . $radius . ")";

            // Return the updated WHERE part of the query  
            return $where;

        }
```

This code works fine, however, I've used the wp_geo_posts plugin before, and that lets you output onto the screen the distance each event is from the users location using `<?php echo $post->distance; ?>`

With this code, there is no 'distance' output to the `$post` variable. Is there a way of getting this to output to `$post` so it can be displayed on the front end?

Comment: You are probably not returning that value in your query. Why not construct the whole query manually?

Comment: Maybe it would be better off setting `distance` as post meta, on a vanilla install, you really can't add anything to the `post` object, you have to use `post_meta` to define a relationship between custom / external data and your post object.

Comment: Oh okay, I've seen in some scripts people use `AS distance` (distance used as an example), then reference 'distance' in the post object. If the distance was in post-meta would this be possible?